# Howto return every n-th row without using the standard mod method

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database which saves cryptocurrency price data. A request for price data looks like this:

```
SELECT timestamp, price FROM PRICES 
WHERE timestamp > 1504703321 
AND timestamp < 1504707321 
AND exchange = (SELECT exid FROM EXCHANGES WHERE name = "exchange_name") 
AND market = (SELECT mid FROM MARKETS WHERE name = "market_name") 
AND side = (SELECT sid FROM SIDES WHERE name = "ASK") 
AND id % 2 = 0 
ORDER BY timestamp ASC";
```

Should be pretty straight forward. In order to keep this post short, I do not write down more information about other tables. If you need more information though, please feel free to ask and I will add it.

As you can see I use the "standard" mod method (`AND id % 2 = 0`) to get every second row. However, I am experiencing a problem:

The program which fills the table with data always adds new data in the same order. Say I have two exchanges, named `A` with `exid 1` and `B` with `exid 2`. First, a row for `A` is added, then a row for `B`, then a row for `A` again, then `B` again and so on.

The result would be:

```
id    exchange    ...
1        1        ...
2        2        ...
3        1        ...
4        2        ...
```

For every `id % 2` where `exchange = 1` the result is always `!= 0`, meaning the result form the above query will be empty.

If possible in any way, I'd like to solve this problem solely by modifing the SQL-Statement, meaning the database / tables and software remain unchanged, and losing as little performance as possible. The table can grow up to 4 million rows.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Do you need every Nth row for _each_ exchange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery and add a new column:

```
SELECT timestamp, price
FROM (SELECT p.timestamp, p.price, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
     FROM PRICES p CROSS JOIN
          (SELECT @rn := 0) params
     WHERE timestamp > 1504703321 AND
           timestamp < 1504707321 AND
           exchange = (SELECT exid FROM EXCHANGES WHERE name = 'exchange_name') AND
           market = (SELECT mid FROM MARKETS WHERE name = 'market_name') AND
           side = (SELECT sid FROM SIDES WHERE name = 'ASK') 
    ) p
WHERE rn % 2 = 0
ORDER BY timestamp ASC;
```

Comment: you need `order by` in the inner query as well.